# Will departing to a third country for a Master's instead of returning home negatively affect my B2 US Tourist Visa application?

Tags: usa, visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas

If I intend to visit a friend in the US and then depart to a third country to begin my Master’s Program rather than fly back to my country, will this negatively impact my application for a B2 Tourist Visa to the US? I'm no longer working because my studies in the third country are starting soon.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you *physically* leave the US on a plane bound for your home country or directly to the place where you embark on further studies has no significance whatsoever for the visa decision.

In your application you need to make a case that it will be *in your own best selfish interest* to **leave the US** after the visit you propose. There is, objectively speaking, nothing that pulls you back to your home country strongly enough for this, as evidenced by the fact you're planning to go away to study for several years elsewhere. So your only hope for the visa application is to argue that the master's program you will be joining is so attractive that it's a better choice for you than staying in the US as an undocumented immigrant would be.

This is not *quite* a routine situation, and it would be hard to make a guess at your chances. But playing games with your physical itinerary is not going to influence it.

.. with one caveat, namely that if going directly to your new home means that you will *travel with a lot of baggage* that you otherwise would have left home and picked up later, *that* can make it look at the border like you're intending to move to the US for good, which will mean trouble. But if you're traveling reasonably light and getting most of your possessions shipped separately to the place where you will study, there'll be no particular problem there.

Comment: That's a great answer, Henning. 

You are right. I do actually have an apartment in my name in my home country, and my parents and sibling all live here - but you are right, I don't have a job now because well, I can very well afford not to work and would like to travel before I start school in the third country. 

Any ideas how I can prove that my Master's is attractive? I thought paying the full tuition fee of the first year and already booking my accommodation would be more than sufficient. We're talking more than EURO 10,000 all paid up! 

What do you mean by physical itinerary?

Comment: Yes, I would say showing papers that show you already paid to ship your possessions to the third country, and are packing light for this diversion via the US, would aid your case rather than hurt it.

Comment: @dante: By "physical itinerary" I simply mean which planes you will be physically on when going from point A to point B. The point of the lecture was merely to make the point that you _should not_ try to hide the fact that you're going to such-and-such place to study (due to some misunderstood advice claiming they want you to go back _to your home country_ specifically).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Oh. I guess that's why I asked the question. Most of the questions I see about B2 Visa is about trying to prove that you're returning home. But I'm NOT returning home because I'm going somewhere else to be studying. So, since I don't see people who ask questions from that perspective, I'm just very nervous about the whole thing. Someone even suggested I hire an immigration lawyer to help me with this.

Comment: @Harper Oh. Actually I've been traveling around Europe and Southeast Asia recently with just a suitcase and duffel bag. Everything I own is in those 2 bags. I don't own a lot of stuff. Just the bare essentials. Do you think traveling around Europe would help my cause with the B2 Visa? (My country of further study is also in Europe)

Comment: @dante well, the way immigration works is they make a presumption that you plan to immigrate, and then cheerfully allow you to prove otherwise.  Duffelbagging around the world paints a bad picture; it shows you are wandering, at loose ends.  *Especially a concern in affluent countries*, where they worry you'll find opportunity/reason to overstay (well paying job; romance partner creating path to citizenship).  You'll need to *firmly* rebut that by showing a life plan that requires you to move on.

Comment: @Harper Okay. That's a new one. I've been told having a good travel history helps in getting a B2 visa. But now you've said otherwise. I've never overstayed or worked illegally in any country ever. That's not how I roll. But I do enjoy traveling. The only difference between me and most travelers is I really do bring everything  with me when I travel - because, besides owning an apartment, I don't really own any other material goods besides a laptop and some clothes and a suitcase. I never expected being a traveler would be a negative point for a visa.  Bummer.

Comment: If you've already got your student visa then I don't see a problem.

Comment: @dante No.  I'm not contradicting what you say there.   It *does* help you that you duffelbagged high-overstay-tendency countries like the UK *and then left as agreed*.  Yes, credit is earned!  However my point also applies; they presume you aim to overstay/seek employ, and you must show an array of evidence to the contrary. I don't think you'll have a huge problem with that; **I just want you to be aware that litmus-test *exists*** -- so you know what documents to bring.

Comment: @Harper Well, I can say that your answers have been immensely helpful. I just see so many conflicting answers online. I see so many people telling me "Oh, you quit your job before school starts? You're not coming back? Well! You're not going to get your visa! Don't bother!" that I've become rather discouraged. I'm still debating whether to hire a lawyer who specializes in US visas (there are a few). I guess I just don't like the idea of having a visa application refused. I've never had one refused, so getting one would be like a huge black demerit point that might affect my future travels.